# Написание "не" с прилагательными.

Tags: частица-не, прилагательные

Конкретный случай. К статье сделан комментарий: "художественный перевод, (не)точный".
Как здесь правильнее писать - слитно или раздельно?

Answer (score 2):

Присоединяюсь к мнению Сержа, здесь желательно слитное написание: художественный перевод, неточный.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

В предложениях такой структуры возможны оба варианта, поэтому выбор делается по семантическому принципу.

Здесь прилагательные "художественный и неточный" являются сближенными по значению и раскрывают одну тему: перевод художественный, неточный.

При раздельном же написании мы имели бы такой смысл: перевод не точный, а художественный, а это не соответствует действительному значению слов.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: неточный.